# grunt js-hint: write output file of errors not working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I'm trying to use grunt with jshint and jshint-log-reporter, and can't get it to write the output file.

I have installed jshint and jshint-log-reporter.

My Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
jshint: {
    options: {
      jshintrc : '.jshintrc',
      reporter: require('jshint-log-reporter'),
      reporterOutput: 'WebContent/js/report.log'
    },
    files: {
        src: ["WebContent/js/**/*.js"]
    }
}......
```

When i execute grunt, the jshint task seems to work, BUT- no file is created or edited.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Are there errors in any of the files linted? (the reporter only creates a log file if there are errors).

Comment: Yes there are. and they are printed in the console instead of being written to a file.